# Wiring library object with property using Guice

Tags: java, guice

I need to inject parameters into a constructor of an object (`Template`) from a library, which means that I cannot annotated that object. The constructor parameters are loaded from a property file:

```
foo=value1
bar=value2

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    private Properties properties;

    public void configure() {
        Names.bindProperties(binder(), getProperties());
        bind(Template.class);
    }

    public Properties getProperties() {
        if (properties == null) {
            loadProperties();
        }
        return properties;
    }

    private loadProperties() {
       ...
    }
    ....
}
```

If I had the source for Template, I would have  annotated its constructor:

```
public class Template {
    @Inject
    public Template(@Named("foo") String foo, @Named("bar") String bar) {
       ....
    }
    ....
 }
```

What can be done absent the ability to annotate the source to inject the parameters from a property file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use a Provider method in your module:

```
@Provides
public Template newTemplate(@Named("foo") String foo, @Named("bar") String bar) {
    return new Template(foo, bar);
}
```

**Note**: As Nathan stated above, this approach will not allow guice aop on the template instance, since it was not created by guice. If this is important, you will have to work with subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

You could sub-class the object and then annotate the constructor of your sub-class. Then you could bind the class to your sub-class. The disadvantage of using a provider method where you create the class with "new" is that this object is not eligible for interception. Your annotated sub-class, however, can be intercepted. Then if you ever need to change the implementation, you have not referenced your sub-class all over your code, only the concrete class that you wanted to inject.